# In my React Native application I cannot check when a user installed the app from a Branch.io link in Android

Tags: android, react-native, deep-linking, branch.io

I'm adding Branch.io in my react native application and already successfully passed the linking process.

Right now I'm making tests for when a user installs the app simulating the install as the documentation say.  For iOS the process works fine, when I click the link the App Store opens then I proceed to close it and install the app via Xcode and when the app opens the "getFirstReferringParams" have the is_first_session field as true, and the dashboard shows that.

The problem is for Android. Following the same process, I get the same answer to the app from the "getFirstReferringParams"  but in the dashboard only count one more for the field "clicks" and "opens" but the field "install" remains unchanged, I am unable to know if the app was installed by using this link.

Any suggestions? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Jackie from Branch here.

Can you please test your implementation using the Liveview page (dashboard.branch.io/liveview)? Liveview is a real-time debugging tool that will display events as they occur. Please follow the instruction here: https://docs.branch.io/pages/exports/pba-liveview/#getting-started

If the install event is still missing, can you send over your Branch app ID and the link(s) you’re using to integrations@branch.io so that our team can investigate further?

Comment: Hi @JackieChoi, after test in the LiveView page  (dashboard.branch.io/liveview) when the android installs the app the event shows in the table of the LiveView. But isn't show in the dashboard still. What could be the problem?

Comment: Which dashboard view are you looking at?